# Print tag folder in vim

Tags: vim, vimrc, vimscript, ctags

I got this line in my .vimrc so that it look i parent directories untill it find a tag file.

```
set tags=./tags;
```

Is there a way to print the directory where vim found the tag file inside vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.vimrc`:

```
map <F7> :echo join(tagfiles(), ',')<CR>
```

Change `<F7>` to some currently unused key... check assignments with  `:nmap`